# can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' for datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

df = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")

child_dict = {'date_of_birth', 'sex', 'weight' , 'height' }

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    child_dict["date_of_birth"] = row["Admissiondate"][i] - timedelta(days=(row["Age(Month)"][i] *30.4374))
    child_dict["sex"] = row["Sex"][i]
    child_dict["weight"] = row["Kg"][i]
    child_dict["height"] = row["Cm"][i]
```

I want to write this code but I can't fully progress.
My Admission date data are like "dd-mm-yyyy"

admission date == Hastane yatış

I also used the pd.astype("str") function for admission date, but I think it wants this number.

How can I improve this.

[image]
Thats My data set preview

Comment: What is it you want to achieve ultimately? In general, to do timedelta arithmetic, you'll have to parse string to datetime data type. e.g. `df["Admissiondate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Admissiondate"], dayfirst=True)`

Comment: Next general thing is you basically want to get rid of the for loop and work with pandas Series, not individual elements. Just as in my comment above, with pd.to_datetime. If your end result should be a dict, you could still convert df to dict at the end.

Answer (score 1):

try this, you need to multiply days by number and not the pure date

```
child_dict["date_of_birth"] = row["Admissiondate"][i] - timedelta(days=(row["Age(Month)"][i])*30.4374)
```

Comment: Thank you(spasibo).
I am getting the same error again;
can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'